# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Helpers\LogHelper' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with this laravel php code, I'm running it on xampp right now, when Install the website (Called uCloud from codecanyon) i get this error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Helpers\LogHelper' not found in D:\Testsfolder\Xampp\htdocs\app\core\Framework.class.php:20 Stack trace: #0 D:\Testsfolder\Xampp\htdocs\index.php(20): App\Core\Framework::run() #1 {main} thrown in D:\testsfolder\Xampp\htdocs\app\core\Framework.class.php on line 20

this is part of the code from framework.class.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Core;

use App\Core\Database;
use App\Helpers\BannedIpHelper;
use App\Helpers\CoreHelper;
use App\Helpers\PluginHelper;
use App\Helpers\LogHelper;
use App\Helpers\RouteHelper;
use App\Helpers\SessionHelper;

class Framework
{
    const VERSION_NUMBER = '2.0.1';

    public static function run() {
        self::init();
        self::autoload();
        LogHelper::initErrorHandler();
        self::registerSession();
        self::postInit();
        self::dispatch();
    }
```

and this is the whole code from index.php (don't know if you'll need it):

```
<?php

/**
 * Entry point. All requests are forwarded via .htaccess/mod_rewrite
 *
 * i.e. index.php?url=http://urlsample.com/controller/action/
 *
 * @author      MFScripts.com - info@mfscripts.com
 */
// get requesting url
$url = (isset($_GET['_page_url']) && (strlen($_GET['_page_url']))) ? $_GET['_page_url'] : 'index';
$url = str_replace(array('../'), '', $url);
define('_INT_PAGE_URL', $url);

// include framework
use App\Core\Framework;
require_once('app/core/Framework.class.php');

// setup environment and process route
Framework::run();
```

please explain like I'm 5 years old because I don't know nothing about any of this, thank you.

Comment: Did you check that there is a `LogHelper` class in your project?

Comment: yes (LogHelper.class.php) located under app\helpers

Comment: Perhaps, the class name within the code is different than the one in the file-name? I had this problem myself quite a few times.

Comment: In the code it's called LogHelper, the file name is LogHelper.class.php is that the problem if so wouldn't that make all the other helpers has the same issue?

Comment: just to be clear the code isn't mine I got it from codecanyon)

Comment: Could you test if any other Helper class is accessible? Call a method from some other helper class in the `run`  before `LogHelper::initErrorHandler();`. If it will give you similar error, then check that these classes are included in your **composer.json** file

Comment: I just did what you asked, but there is 112 composer.json files within the website folder, which one should I check? edit: using run did gave me the same error just as you said

Comment: composer json we are interested in is located in the root of your project. This is the top composer file. Here you will want to find `autoload`-> `psr-%number%`. Here you would search for something like `"App\\Helpers\\" => "app/Helpers/"`. Please be careful to put correct path on the right part to the folder where your classes are located. Next step would be to open terminal and run `composer dump-autoload`. This should fix the issue

Comment: Be advised, that you need to run `composer dump-autoload` in the root of your project, where this composer file is located.

Comment: there is no composer.json file in the root of the project, the composers are all inside \app\libraries\vendor, to be honest I don't understand most of what you're saying because I'm no programmer myself so most of these words are clueless to me, note: I run xampp on windows just incase that's matter, because when I tried to use composer command it didn't work...

Comment: and there is one extra composer.json file in \app\libraries

Comment: Please go one folder up from **app** folder. There you will find composer.json file. If you don't have composer installed and no `composer.phar` then please install composer in your system. You can find many tutorials on this subject on Google.

Comment: after going one folder up from app folder (basically the root folder) there is no json file, but inside /app/libraries there is composer.json and composer.phar so what do you think?

Comment: It looks like the laravel project was incorrectly installed. Please take a look at this link: [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5#installing-laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5#installing-laravel). If possible, I would suggest creating a completely new laravel project following the tutorial, and then adding the Helper Classes. Also check the version of laravel on that website, so that you follow the instructions for the desired version of laravel

Comment: thank you, will do my best.

Comment: What makes you think this is a Laravel application?

Comment: it has laravel.md in it --_:)_-- don't really know, I just assumed as much, I got another one yesterday for double the price of the first, exact same issue

Comment: [first one](https://codecanyon.net/item/ucloud-file-hosting-script-securely-manage-preview-share-your-files/14341108) [second one](https://yetishare.com/index.html)